# Replacing IF with loops

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with a load of values in and a button.In the code button I have the 
following VBA code

```
If Range("N2").Value = "100" Then
Rows ("2:2").Select
Selection.Delete
 End if
```

The idea is that if 100 is placed in that row then that row will be deleted.But obviously there will be problems if I have loads of rows,this will mean loads of "IFs"
My question is this,is there any way this could be done with a loop.So I could jsut loop through all the rows and if the conditions are met then that Row will be deleted.In the If statement above I have to specify the rows selected,so how would a loop do this??
Any help greatly appreciated.
kind regards
j

Comment: yes, it's possible. But what have you tried for implementing this loop?

Answer (score 3):

`Set` a range and do the following loops

```
For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell in row.Cells
    'Do Something
  Next cell
Next row
```